# How do I calculate the position of a point in HTML5 canvas after rotation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, rotation

After seeing [this](http://codentronix.com/2011/04/27/first-experiment-with-html5-a-wireframe-cube/#comment-2290) code, I can't figure out where does the formula **x * sina + y * cosa** comes from.

After each interval a point rotates around an axes by an **a** angle.

I need the x and z position of the point after the rotation.

In the mentioned article the **x * sina + y * cosa** formula is used. I don't understand from is it derived.

I went through the trigonometric functions an still nothing.

Can anyone help? The basic idea. Some references.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First of all, his code is a projection onto a 3D space, but the question is about a rotation on the Z axis which is the same as a 2D rotation and the Z value is kept the same.*

When you have any given point (x,y) you form a right triangle. Take a look at this picture:

[image]

Now suppose `a` is 15 degrees

[image]

That circle is called a unit-circle and it's radius is `1`.

- The length of the green line along the **Y** axis is the `sine` of the angle.
- The length of the green line along the **X** axis is the `cosine` of the angle.

Note that it doesn't really matter the **size** of the triangle formed by the point's coordinates. As long as it keeps the same angle, the value of the sine and cosine will remain the same as only the section of the triangle within the unit circle matters here.

The `sine` is how much a point should move in the Y axis, and the `cosine` is how much to move in the X axis in order for a point to move in space and **keep** the same angle as a minimum step (their values range from 0 to 1 which is the circle's radius)

But how do you go about moving a point in space in order to **change** it's angle to the origin?

Well, firstly, for any point intersecting the unit circle, meaning the hypotenuse of it's triangle is 1, it's position is `(cosine, sine)`, for a point outside the unit circle, for example `(2,5)`, it's position is `(hypotenuse * cosine, hypotenuse * sine)`

Imagine we have a point `(x,y)` at `a` degrees from the origin and we want to rotate it by `b` degrees, this means we want a new position `(x',y')` where the angle is changed to `a+b` degrees but the distance from the origin (the hypotenuse) is kept the same.

```
x = hypotenuse * cosine(a)
y = hypotenuse * sine(a)

x' = hypotenuse * cosine(a + b)
y' = hypotenuse * sine(a + b)
```

By using the [trigonometric angle adition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) formulas we have that

```
cosine(a + b) = cosine(a) * cosine(b) - sine(a) * sine(b)
sine(a + b) = sine(a) * cosine(b) + cosine(a) * sine(b)
```

If we apply that to our `(x',y')` we get:

```
x' = hypotenuse * cosine(a) * cosine(b) - hypotenuse * sine(a) * sine(b)
y' = hypotenuse * sine(a) * cosine(b) + hypotenuse * cosine(a) * sine(b)
```

If you remember our definition for `(x,y)` you notice that this is the exact same as:

```
x' = x * cosine(b) - y * sine(b)
y' = y * cosine(b) + x * sine(b)
```

And there is your mysterious formula right there on our `y'`, only the order of the addition is reversed.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Had no idea on how to get rid of the a angle, so that the equation would be abstracted to only the b angle.

Comment: How do I apply this formula when I know only the angle of rotation, old x and y? My x and y are calculated from left and top (as its based on browser's implementation of positions), and the rotation happens around the centre. I just need to know the new position of a point in the canvas after it's rotated...

Answer (score 0):

The rotation can be explained e.g. with complex plane.

cos(angle) + i * sin(angle) = e^(i*angle);

Rules of multiplication in complex plane suggests that A*e^(i*angle1) * B*e^(i*angle2), where A and B are the vector lengths. Then multiplying those vectors give A*B*e^(i*(angle1+angle2)) and because the length of cos(angle)+i*sin(angle) is 1, you can rotate a vector A by a complex multiplication without affecting its length.

(X+ i*y) * (cos(angle) + i*sin(angle)) == (x*cos-y*sin)  + i * (x*sin+y*cos)
(Just omit the 'i' term and use the real part as x-coordinate and imag part as y-coordinate.